# Getting 'total_count' from Page Post Likes 'summary' - Facebook PHP SDK (CLOSED)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to PHP and the Facebook PHP SDK and I'm looking to get the `'like_count'` from the `'likes'` `'summary'` of a Facebook page post. My current code contains the following:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=admin_creator,likes.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=30');
$getLikeCount = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
foreach($getLikeCount as $likekey){
    if(isset($likekey['likes'])){
        var_export($likekey['likes']);
        foreach ($likekey['likes'] as $likekey){
            //echo $likekey['total_count'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

The `var_export($likekey['likes']);` exports blank arrays while `var_export($likekey['summary']);` returns NULL. However, in the Graph API Explorer, it returns the following:

```
{
      "admin_creator": {
        "name": "NAME",
        "id": "ID"
      },
      "id": "ID",
      "likes": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 1022,
          "can_like": true,
          "has_liked": false
        }
      }
    },
```

How can I access the `'total_count'` field because accessing it through my methods of `'likes'` and '`summary'` do not work.

**EDIT:** Using `getGraphEdge()->asArray();` will not work because it does not return the summary array. I would somehow have to get the values from `getDecodedBody();` or another method. If I use `$getLikeCount = $response->getDecodedBody();`, with this code:

```
foreach($getLikeCount as $key){
    if(isset($key['admin_creator'])){
        echo $key['admin_creator']['name'];
    }
}
```

It does not return anything. I am using `'admin_creator'` as an example because it works if `$getLikeCount = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();` and doesn't work in my current method however I cannot use this method because I am trying to get the `'total_count'` field from the `'summary'` of post `'likes'` and the `'summary'` does not show in the array when using the `getGraphEdge()` method and only shows when using `getDecodedBody();`. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the values from `getDecodedBody()` or if there's a workaround to get the `total_count` field from `summary`.

**ANSWER:**
Answer can be found below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a work around.

The work around requires finding the post ID and then doing another request to only get the likes field of that post.

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=admin_creator,likes.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=30');
$getPostID = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
foreach($getPostID as $IDKey){
    if(isset($IDKey['id'])){
        $currentPostID = $IDKey['id'];
        $likesResponse = $fb->get('/'.$currentPostID.'/likes?limit=0&summary=true');
        echo $currentPostID . '<br>'; //optional
        $getLikeCount = $likesResponse->getGraphEdge();
        $currentLikeCount = $getLikeCount->getTotalCount();
        echo $currentLikeCount . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find this data without making more API Call.
The summary data is hidden in the metadata of the field **likes**. It's the same for comments and reactions.

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=id,likes.limit(0).summary(true)');
foreach ($reponse->getGraphEdge() as $graphNode) {
    // Some fields can have metadata
    $likesData =  $graphNode->getField('likes')->getMetaData();
    echo 'The total of likes for the post ID "' .  $graphNode->getField('id') . '" is: '. $likesData['summary']['total_count'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$getLikeCount['likes']['summary']['total_count']
```

Comment: I edited the question a bit. The problem seems to be that `getGraphEdge()->asArray();` does not return the `summary` array.